# Ищет Класс "Redis" как собственный. "Class 'Journal3\Opencart\Redis' not found"

Tags: php

В одном из функций класса вызываю `$redis = new Redis()`.

```
namespace Journal3\Opencart;
use Journal3\Utils\Arr;
class Controller extends \Controller implements Autocomplete {}
```

Но ищется он как свой, не находится и выдаёт ошибку `Fatal error: Class 'Journal3\Opencart\Redis' not found`. Хотя Redis подключён и в контексте другого класса вызывается и работает.

Comment: `$redis = new \Redis()`?

Comment: Точно! Корневое пространство имён!